# Что означает параметр линкера GCC -Wl,--no-as-needed?

Tags: gcc, ld

Исходные данные. Есть (статическая) библиотека A, которая зависит от (статических) библиотек B и C, которые в свою очередь зависят от других библиотек. Граф зависимостей достаточно сложен, но циклических зависимостей в нем нет. Я решил написать тесты для библиотеки A, используя CMake и GTest. Сам тест - это исполняемый файл X, который линкуется с библиотеками A, B, C, и остальными.

Проблема заключается в том, что линкер сообщает мне: в библиотеке A присутствуют неопределенные символы. Эти символы находятся в библиотеке B. Порядок линковки, дублирование и обертывание списка библиотек при передаче линкеру в `-Wl,--start-group`/`-Wl,--stop-group` успеха не принесли.

Но проблему удалось решить при помощи параметра `-Wl,--no-as-needed`. Я пробовал искать информацию о том, как это работает, но окончательного понимания не достиг.

Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить мне, как работает `-Wl,--no-as-needed`? И я буду еще более признателен, если мне приведут пример ситуации, в которой этот параметр нужно использовать.

Comment: Скорее всего некорректный порядок библиотек в командной строке: `-lB` должна идти _после_ зависящей от неё `-lA`, иначе линкер посчитает что libB не нужна. `-Wl,--no-as-needed` отключает такое поведение линкера, но рекомендуемое решение - исправить порядок библиотек.

Comment: Проблему с порядком следования должно решать обрамление списка библиотек в -Wl--start-group ... -Wl--stop-group. Но это не помогло.